# How to make plot from file WinAPI

Tags: c++, winapi, plot, win32gui

We have **txt file** with numbers:

*60 0*

*120 4*

*180 20*

*60 -28*

*180 28*

*30 -28*

*30 28*

*30 -28*

*60 0*

I need a plot with first column in horizontal coordinate line and the second column in vertical coordinate line like on [this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RVE7n.png). But now I have smth [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tYKPr.png)

```
std::ifstream omega_file("test.txt");

MoveToEx(hdc, 0, 0, NULL); // start point
double T_new = 0;
while (!omega_file.eof())
{
    omega_file >> T >> Omega;

    T_new = T_new + T;

    LineTo(hdc, T_new / 60 * horizontal_step_grid, - Omega * vertical_step_grid);
    MoveToEx(hdc, T_new / 60 * horizontal_step_grid, - Omega * vertical_step_grid, NULL);
}
```

Comment: To begin with, your usage of `while (!omega_file.eof())` is [wrong](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong).

Comment: and how can i fix it

Comment: Is your code inside a `WM_PAINT` message (callback) ?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/pvrPJzq2 full WM_PAINT part

Comment: *and how can I fix it?* `while (omega_file >> T >> Omega)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to draw two lines (horizontal, then vertical) instead of one per one coordinate.

Also note that [`LineTo()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-lineto) sets the current position, so `MoveToEx()` to the same coordinate is redundant.

Try this:

```cpp
std::ifstream omega_file("test.txt");

MoveToEx(hdc, 0, 0, NULL); // start point
int currentY = 0;
double T_new = 0;
while (omega_file >> T >> Omega)
{

    T_new = T_new + T;

    int x = T_new / 60 * horizontal_step_grid;
    int nextY = - Omega * vertical_step_grid;
    LineTo(hdc, x, currentY);
    LineTo(hdc, x, nextY);
    currentY = nextY;
}
```

Comment: but i understood that now there is a problem with scale. Blue - program plot, red - plot which should be. One horizontal step is 30 seconds (for example, if in first column there is 60, it should be two steps) https://ibb.co/PFf6jC9